# EXIF orientation CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, exif

I'm trying to fix the orientation issue when uploading pictures from mobile devices.
The pictures uploads but no rotation correction is applied.
Using the image manipulation class from Codeigniter.
Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
public function changeimage() {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $sid = $this->session->userdata['user']['id'];
        $files = $_FILES;
        if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
            $format = explode('.', $files['image']['name']);
            $format = end($format);
            $cimagename = md5(uniqid(mt_rand())) . ".$format";
            $_FILES['image']['name'] = $cimagename;
            $_FILES['image']['type'] = $files['image']['type'];
            $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $files['image']['tmp_name'];
            $_FILES['image']['error'] = $files['image']['error'];
            $_FILES['image']['size'] = $files['image']['size'];
            $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', time());
            $date1 = date('Y/m/d ', strtotime($this->input->post('createdon')));
            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options($sid, $date1));
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload("image")) {
                $data['error'] = true;
                $data['errormsg'] = "Something went wrong";
                echo $data['errormsg'];
            } else {
                $data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());
                $image_info = $this->upload->data();
                $this->load->library('image_lib');
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $files;
                $config['new_image'] = $files;
                $exif = exif_read_data($config['source_image']);
                if ($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
                    $ort = $exif['Orientation'];
                    if ($ort == 6 || $ort == 5)
                        $config['rotation_angle'] = '270';
                    if ($ort == 3 || $ort == 4)
                        $config['rotation_angle'] = '180';
                    if ($ort == 8 || $ort == 7)
                        $config['rotation_angle'] = '90';
                }
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->image_lib->rotate()) {
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->load->library("image_lib");
                $config['image_library'] = "gd2";
                $config['library_path'] = '/login/application/libraries/';
                $config['source_image'] = "assets/userimages/" . $image_info['file_name'];
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config['rotation_angle'] = '';
                $sizes = array(array("name" => "thumb", "width" => "200", "height" => "227"));
                foreach ($sizes as $size) {
                    $config['new_image'] = "assets/userimages/" . $size['name'] . "_" . $image_info['file_name'];
                    $config['width'] = $size['width'];
                    $config['height'] = $size['height'];
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sets the source image name/path. The path must be a relative or absolute server path, not a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This library worked for me:

```
class Rotateimage {

    /*
     * @param string $setFilename - Set the original image filename
     * @param array $exifData - Set the original image filename
     * @param string $savedFilename - Set the rotated image filename
     */

    private $setFilename    = "";
    private $exifData       = "";
    private $degrees        = "";

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function setfile($setFilename){
        try{
            if(!file_exists($setFilename)){
                throw new Exception('File not found.');
            } 
            $this->setFilename = $setFilename;
        } catch (Exception $e ) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        } 
    }

    /*
     * EXTRACTS EXIF DATA FROM THE JPEG IMAGE
     */
    public function processExifData(){
        $orientation = 0;
        $this->exifData = exif_read_data($this->setFilename);
        foreach($this->exifData as $key => $val){
            if(strtolower($key) == "orientation" ){
                $orientation = $val;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( $orientation == 0 ){
            $this->_setOrientationDegree(1);
        }
        $this->_setOrientationDegree($orientation); 
    } 

    /*
     * DETECTS AND SETS THE IMAGE ORIENTATION
     * Orientation flag info  http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html
     */
    private function _setOrientationDegree($orientation){
       switch($orientation):
           case 1: 
               $this->degrees = 0;
               break;
           case 8:
               $this->degrees = 90;
               break;
           case 3:
               $this->degrees = 180;
               break;
           case 6:
               $this->degrees = 270;
               break;
       endswitch;
       $this->_rotateImage();
    }  


    /*
     * ROTATE THE IMAGE BASED ON THE IMAGE ORIENTATION
     */
    private function _rotateImage(){
        if($this->degrees < 1 ){
            return FALSE;
        }
        $image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->setFilename);
        return imagerotate($image_data, $this->degrees, 0);  
    } 


    /*
     * SAVE THE IMAGE WITH THE NEW FILENAME
     */
    public function savedFileName($savedFilename){
        if($this->degrees < 1 ){
            return false;   
        }
        $imageResource = $this->_rotateImage();
        if($imageResource == FALSE){
            return false;   
        }
        imagejpeg($imageResource, $savedFilename);  
    } 

}
```